# Is it possible to list channels stored in a Group?

Tags: django, django-channels, django-channels-presence

Is it possible to access the list of channels added in a Group with django-channels?

```
def consumer(message):
    Group("group_name").add(message.reply_channel)
    channel_list = Group("group_name").???
```

**EDIT:**

What I try to achieve is to have access to sessions of all channel, like the list of connected users for instance.

Thus far I use a database based system that lists the connections. But if the server shuts down without executing my ws_disconnect consumers, these connections object will remain in database, and I don't want this.

**EDIT 2:**

To list the connected users, I found `django-channels-presence`. I'll test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested [`django-channels-presence`](http://django-channels-presence.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I easily succeeded to list the connected users for a `Group` by creating a `Room` (that handle `Group` management/creation, `channel` adding/removing...) and that provides a `get_users()` method that permits me to achieve what I was searching for.

It also provides a way to clean added channels that aren't deleted if the server crashes (that wouldn't trigger the ws_disconnect consumer that is used to delete these channels from the group). It provides the `prune_presence` and `prune_room` tasks that cleans expired channels.

Comment: Answer is useless without any snippet

Comment: This plugin adds multiple new database tables, it may be overkill for what you need

Answer (score 7):

Yeah that's possible. And the easy hack is...

```
# Get channel_layer function
from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer

# passing group_channel takes channel name
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
ch_group_list = channel_layer.group_channels('<your group name>')
```

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to access some informations like the associated session/user too? :)

Comment: channels ships with `@channel_session_user_from_http` decorator and in consumers function you can get the user from `message.user` is that what you want

Comment: I know that but doesn't it only applies on the current `message` consumer's parameter?
what I got with the `get_channel_layer(),group_channels()` function was a dictionnary associating strings to floats : (`{'websocket.send!dLCNWvEM': 1473714104.796983}`). How can I access the defails of each channel? For instance to list the connected users?

Comment: @ShreeRangaRaju Mm let me check and get back to you on this...

Answer (score 3):

i found that `channel_layer.group_channels('<your group name>')`, mentioned above, did not work on channels 2. So , i decide to save information that i need in channel_layer, and it work.

### version info

- channels==2.1.5
- aioredis==1.2.0
- channels-redis==2.3.2

In my case, i need know the channels number in a group, because i start a celery beat in the background for keep pushing data to channels, but when the last channel in the group disconnect, i want to stop the celery beat.

I count the channels in a group by store it in channel_layer.

### on connect

```
count = getattr(self.channel_layer, self.group_name, 0)
if not count:
    setattr(self.channel_layer, self.group_name, 1)
else:
    setattr(self.channel_layer, self.group_name, count + 1)
```

### on disconnect

```
count = getattr(self.channel_layer, self.group_name, 0)
setattr(self.channel_layer, self.group_name, count - 1)
if count == 1:
    delattr(self.channel_layer, self.group_name)

    # stop my celery beat
```

Comment: This is dangerous. Async consumers may lead to race condition and there is no disconnect event/method you can rely on.

Answer (score 3):

You can optionally persist users connected in a room in a database. Create a room, add users on connect, and remove users on disconnect.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async


# ./models
class Room(models.Model):
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), related_name='rooms')

    @classmethod
    @sync_to_async
    def add(cls, room_name, user):
        room, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(room_name=room_name)
        room.users.add(user)
        return created # sockets => join or create



    @classmethod
    @sync_to_async
    def users_count(cls, room_name):
        rooms = cls.objects.filter(room_name=room_name)
        if rooms.exists():
            return rooms.first().users.count()
        return 0

    @classmethod
    @sync_to_async
    def remove_user(cls, user, room_name):
        room = cls.objects.filter(room_name=room_name)
        if room.exists():
            room.users.remove(user)


# ./consumer.py
class YourConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'video_%s' % self.room_name
        self.group_users = {self.scope.get('user').id: 1}

        if self.scope.get('user').is_authenticated:
            room = await Room.add(self.room_name, self.scope.get('user'))

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        if self.scope.get('user').is_authenticated:
            await Room.remove_user(self.room_name, self.scope.get('user'))

    async def websocket_receive(self, message):
        count = await Room.users_count(room_name=self.room_name)
        await self.send(json.dumps({
            'type': 'websocket.send',
            'text': 'pong',
            'group': self.room_group_name,
            'room': self.room_name,
            'connections': count
        }))
```

Answer (score 0):

i create object in `AuthMiddlewareStack`

```
class TokenAuthMiddleware:
    handler: MessengerHandler = None

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    async def generate_object(self):
        if self.handler is None: # just for first time
            self.handler= MessengerHandler()
            await self.handler.import_key()
        return self.handler

    async def __call__(self, scope, send, rec):
        model = await self.generate_object()
        scope["handler"] = model
        return await self.inner(scope, send, rec)
```

in `AsyncWebsocketConsumer` class

```
@property
    def _get_handler(self) -> MessengerHandler:
        return self.scope["handler"]
```

connect

```
 self._get_handler.add_new_channel(self.channel_name, self.user_api.user_id)
```

disconnect

```
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        if self.user_api.is_active:
            self._get_handler.remove_channel(self.channel_name, self.user_api.user_id)
        pass
```

MessengerHandler

```
class MessengerHandler:

    channels: dict[int, ClientChannels] = {}


    def add_new_channel(self, channel: str, user_id: int):
        ....
    def remove_channel(self, channel: str, user_id: int):
       ....

    def get_user_channels(self, user_id: int, without_channel: str = None) -> list:
...
```

otherwise safe thread
using [Django-Redis](https://pypi.org/project/django-redis/) package

handle channels

```
    @staticmethod
    def add_new_channel(channel: str, user_id: int, client_type: str, client_id: int):
        channel_name = f"u_{user_id}_{client_type}_{client_id}"
        cache.set(channel_name, channel, timeout=None)

    @staticmethod
    def remove_channel(channel_type: str, user_id: int, client_id: int):
        channel_name = f"u_{user_id}_{channel_type}_{client_id}"
        cache.delete(channel_name)

    @staticmethod
    def get_user_channels(user_id: int) -> list:
        channel_name = f"u_{user_id}_*"
        values = cache.get_many(cache.keys(channel_name))
        return [v for k, v in values.items()]
```